# Problems with running WMV in VB.Net

Tags: dll, wmv, vb.net-2010

I just finished building my program, but I noticed that vb.net (2010) creates two dll files ( AxInterop.WMPLib.dll & Interop.WMPLib.dll ), when I tried to run the application without having those two files in the same directory, it crashed right away!!!

Is there a way, to have the WMV components running without using any additional libraries, so I can distribute the exe file only?!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a program called smartassembly, to protect the source of my program.

The program itself asked me if I want to merge dependencies (resources), so I picked the two dll files, and it me out one executable file, with no dll files at all.

Comment: It's super that you got it. However, could you provide your solution, for the benefit of the community? Otherwise, ask for your question to be deleted. Thanks!

Comment: Sure MPelletier, I used a program called smartassembly, to protect the source of my program. The program itself asked me if I want to merge dependencies (resources), so I picked the two dll files, and it me out one executable file, with no dll files at all!!!